# how to pass instanced between mutiple files and classes

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, instance, multiple-instances

Suppose i'm writing a software that it has about 50 classes.
We can divide classes into 2 part:
1. classes we forced to create instance for more that of once instance.
2. classes we just create a one instance until end of program.

So, suppose i have MainProgram class and everything do here, then just
make an instance in main.cpp and run my program.
Now, I need to pass instances created just once (option 2) to other classes, Do you
have any idea to implement to this?
Because i can't `new` again. i just work with old instance.For example:
I wrote a `SocketNetwork Class` that its constructor get port number and `bind` to it.
So i can't `rebind` again and i forced to access to resoures of the given port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're looking for the [**singleton pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

It goes something like:

```
class A
{
public:
   static A& getInstance()
   {
      static A a;
      return a;
   }
private:
   A() {}
};
```

Because the constructor is private, you can only get the single instance of `A` that is created through the `getInstance()` method, which you can call anywhere.

```
`A::getInstance()`
```

will always return the same instance of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Before SingleTone, I used :

```
class AudioCallbackData
{
public:
    AudioCallbackData();
    AudioMixer *audioMixer;
    AudioBuilder *AbRcv;
    NetworkSocket *socketAudio;
    NetworkSocket *socketCommand;
    NetworkSocket *socketSetting;
    NetworkSocket *socketStatus;
    NetworkSocket *socketData;
    MainCore *mainCorePtr;
    AudioCore *audioCorePtr;
    Device *devPtr;
    CircularBuffer *cBuffer;

};
extern AudioCallbackData  *audioCallbackDataPtr;// = ptr;
```

Every attribute keeps instance of a class.So for SingleTone, Now for each instance may i write a class for each instance?

Comment: It's singleton, not singletone.

Comment: Do you have some pressing need to use pointers to everything (e.g. to control when they're created, or to change polymorphically between implementations at runtime)?  If not, you could just make them member variables.  Separately, do you need to use a singleton?  They have various issues (please search).  Alternatively, an `AudioCallbackData` object created in `main()` with a reference  passed down through the call stack is often a better practice.

Comment: If i use SingleTon, May i define a class for each instance?

Comment: one of the issues with singleton is that it ties the restriction of a single instance to the type, so you would be forced to have only one `NetworkSocket` for audio, command, setting, status and data. I would tend to create one the AudioCallbackData object in main as @TonyDelroy said, and have the objects returned as references by accessors rather than it just being a struct ( so you can vary implementation without having to update client code ).